# java.io.FileNotFoundException using FileOutputStream

Tags: linux, fileoutputstream

I have just completed one of my large java projects on a linux machine, I now attempt to run it on windows 10 and I have received [an error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oWIX4.jpg).

Here is an image of the relevent code, and error.
It says using a FileOutputStream when a file is not found, it will create it. I have already completed my project fully on a linux machine, and im not sure why this is happening now on windows 10.

Thanks

Comment: "The system cannot find the path specified" => the path is incorrect. Verify that your current working directory is correct and that folders are not missing.

Comment: I have manually checked the directories on the desktop, and all directories do exist.

Answer (score 0):

From [Javadocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html#FileOutputStream(java.lang.String,%20boolean)) :

> If the file exists but is a directory rather than a regular file, **does
>   not exist but cannot be created**, or cannot be opened for any other
>   reason then a FileNotFoundException is thrown.

It will throw a `FileNotFoundException` if the file doesn't exist and cannot be created (doc), but it will create it if it can. To be sure you probably should first test that the file exists before you create the FileOutputStream (and create with createNewFile() if it doesn't).

```
File yourFile = new File("score.txt");
yourFile.createNewFile(); // if file already exists will do nothing 
FileOutputStream oFile = new FileOutputStream(yourFile, false);
```